# Radio-active elements in the Earth`s core

Tags: science-based, nuclear

What would happen if the earth`s core was made of radio-active elements?
No website is giving the answer

Comment: Hi user46235. What would happen with what? The shape of human buildings? Jupiter's orbit? Earth's surface gravity? The number of mosquitoes in Zimbabwe? Generally, questions on the form "what would be the effects on society of X?" (for some given "X") are considered too broad, and this seems to me to be even broader because you don't even ask about society, but something even less bounded. Also, how is this related to climate change? Please [Edit] your question to clarify what you're asking, or it may be at risk of being closed (as it currently stands, likely as "too broad").

Comment: Why do you think the Earth's core is not made of radioactive elements?  Because it is: http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2011/jul/19/radioactive-decay-accounts-for-half-of-earths-heat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radioactive decay is the reason why some planet core is still molten. This is also the case for Earth.

Radioactive elements decay, emitted radiation (be it gamma, beta or alpha) is absorbed by the atoms in the core and converted to heat.

Mars is believed to have lost this heat source some time ago, undergoing shrinkage (which is supposed to be the trigger for the creation of Valles Marineris) and losing the dynamo generating the magnetic field.